# Iterate through an array and convert all character codes to characters?

Tags: javascript, loops, character-encoding

I've coded myself into a hole and though it would be easier to start again, there is still a lesson to be learned here (it's just practice anyway).

I'm building a caesar cipher which will accept two parameters: the message, and the cipher key. Each letter is compared to its corresponding letter in the cipher key, then changed to a new character code.

I'm having a hell of a time figuring out how to turn an array of character codes into an array (or better yet, a string) of characters.

Here's my code:

```js
function cipher(message, cipherKey) {

 //convert the message and cipher key to arrays of their character codes
 var messageArr = message.toLowerCase().split("").map(x => x.charCodeAt() - 97);
 var cipherKeyArr = cipherKey.toLowerCase().split("").map(x => x.charCodeAt() - 97);

 //create new array for the ciphered array, which will turn back to a string
 var cipheredArr = [];

 //loop through both the cipher key value and message key value to 
 //create the ciphered array

 for (var i = 0; i < messageArr.length; i++) {
  cipheredArr[i] = messageArr[i] + cipherKeyArr[i];
  if (cipheredArr[i] >= 26) {}
 }

 //go through the ciphered array and make it loop back through
 //the alphabet once it goes past z
 for (var i = 0; i < cipheredArr.length; i++) {
  if (cipheredArr[i] >= 26) {cipheredArr[i] = cipheredArr[i] - 26;}
 }

//display on webpage
return cipheredArr;
   }
```

So the cipheredArr is an array of numbers (character codes) but I can't find a good way to iterate through it and change them back into letters. The .fromCharCode() syntax is confusing me for this purpose.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sample input and expected output is really helpful in offering a handle to use in answering your question. In other words, how are you calling this function, what's the output of this call, and how does that not meet your expectations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an array of characters for an array of character codes, use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var chars = codes.map(code => String.fromCharCode(code));
```

(Note: Just `codes.map(String.fromCharCode)` won't work, `String.fromCharCode` would make inappropriate use of the second and third arguments `map` passes the callback.)

To get a *string* from those codes:

```
// ES2015+
var str = String.fromCharCode(...codes);

// ES5 and earlier:
var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, codes);
```

`fromCharCode` returns a string made up of the code units you pass it as discrete arguments ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) | [spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-string.fromcharcode)).

Comment: Thank you so much! I did it this way:

var charArr = cipheredArr.map(code => String.fromCharCode(code + 97)).join().replace(/,/g,"");


It's ugly and inelegant but it works! Next time I create something like this I'll hopefully think of a neater way before I code myself into a hole. Good to know that I can dig out though! Thanks again.